# Apply ItemTemplate to LongListSelector in code behind

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I've defined a DataTemplate for the items in my LongListSelector in the page resources and now I want to apply this DataTemplate to an LongListSelector in the code behind file. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple:

```
'NameOfList'.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["'NameOfDataTemplate'"] as DataTemplate;
```